# Use UIImagePickerController Record Video but not sound

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have problem in recording the video.After recording the video I am not having sound of the video.My coding is below.

```
 - (void)StartVideo

 {

    self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    _imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;


     _imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    _imagePickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium;

    _imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 10;

    _imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;

    _imagePickerController.showsCameraControls  = NO;

    _imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

    _imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;

   if(!self.CameraLvingVCLayer)

   {

      self.CameraLvingVCLayer = [[CameraFaceLivingCreditViewController alloc] init];

      self.CameraLvingVCLayer.delegate = self;
   }

  _imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = self.CameraLvingVCLayer.view;

  _imagePickerController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

  _imagePickerController.toolbarHidden = YES;

  _imagePickerController.delegate = self;

  [self presentViewController:_imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil]; }


 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

   {

     NSString* mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"])

    {

        NSURL* mediaURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

       if(mediaURL)

       {

          NSString *moviePath = [mediaURL path];

          if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) 

          {

            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);

          }

        }
    }
}
```

There's no sound in my recording video,why? Please Go through my coding and give the solution for this.
Please help me

Comment: Please be more precise to what you posted

Comment: Thats unheard with UImagePickerController. Did you accidentally tap "No" when the "App would like to use your Microphone prompt" came up for the first time?

Comment: APP didn't tip me to use a microphone when it started.